# Kernel of composition of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f : U \to V$ and $g : V \to W$ be linear transformations on the vector spaces $U$, $V$, and $W$. Supposedly,

$$
\dim(\ker(g \circ f)) = \dim(\ker(f)) + \dim(\ker(g) \cap \operatorname{im}(f)).
$$

How might I go about proving that?

---

*(Attempt:)* The $\dim(\ker(g)\cap\operatorname{im}(f))$ term suggests to me that I should define a vector space $V' = \ker(g) + \operatorname{im}(f)$ to invoke the theorem that

$$
\dim(V') = \dim(\ker(g)) + \dim(\operatorname{im}(f)) - \dim(\ker(g) \cap \operatorname{im}(f)),
$$

but I don't really see where to go from there.

Comment: First of all I would notice that $\ker(f)\cap \ker(g)\cap \operatorname{im}(f)=\emptyset$. Then I would also notice that $\ker(g\circ f)=(\ker(g)\cap \ker(f))\cup (\ker(g)\cap\operatorname{im}(f))$. Does this helps?

Comment: @uforoboa: I don't think that $\ker(f)\cap\ker(g)\cap\operatorname{im}(f) = \emptyset$. For example, let $U=V=W=\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=0$, and $g(x)=0$. Then $\ker(f)=\mathbb{R}$, $\ker(g)=\mathbb{R}$, and $\operatorname{im}(f)=\{0\}$, so $\ker(f)\cap\ker(g)\cap\operatorname{im}(f)=\{0\} \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: @Snowball.. you're right... I meant $\{0\}$ not $\emptyset$ of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**: Use two different expressions for $\text{dim}(U)$ in terms of the maps as well as an expression for $\text{dim}(\text{Im}(f))$ in terms of the map $g$.

**HINT 2**: You can view $g$ as acting on $\text{Im}(f)$ alone. What does that tell you about $\text{dim}(\text{Im}(f))$ ?

---

From my first hint, one was meant to derive:

$$\dim(U) = \dim(\ker(f)) + \dim(\text{Im}(f))$$

and

$$\dim(U) = \dim(\ker(g\circ f)) + \dim(\text{Im}(g \circ f))$$

and from my second hint, that

$$\dim(\text{Im(f)}) = \dim(ker(g)\cap\text{Im}(f)) + \dim(\text{Im}(g \circ f)) \; .$$

Comment: Sorry, that should have been $\text{dim}(\text{Im}(f))$. Corrected.

Comment: $\dim(U) = \dim(\ker(f)) + \dim(\operatorname{im}(f)) = \dim(\ker(g \circ f) + \operatorname{im}(g \circ f))$, so that reduces the problem to showing that $\dim(\operatorname{im}(f)) = \dim(\operatorname{im}(g \circ f)) + \dim(\ker(g) \cap \operatorname{im}(f))$. I still don't quite see what sort of expression for $\dim(\operatorname{im}(f))$ I should be looking for, though.

Comment: OK, I'll add an extra hint.

Comment: Thanks! Let $g' : \operatorname{im}(f) \to W$. Then $\dim(\operatorname{im}(f)) = \dim(\ker(g')) + \dim(\operatorname{im}(g'))$. $\ker(g') = \ker(g) \cap \operatorname{im}(f)$ and $\operatorname{im}(g') = \operatorname{im}(g \circ f)$, proving the identity. I probably would not have thought of *hint 2* on my own. What led you to come up with it?

Comment: I just wrote down all the possible relations I could come up with and combined them.

Comment: By rank-nullity theorem, 
$$\begin{align}\dim (U) &= \dim(N_{g\circ f})+\dim(R_{g\circ f})\\ \dim(U)&= \dim (N_f)+\dim (R_f)\\ \dim(V)&= \dim(N_g)+\dim (R_g).\end{align}$$ Thus $$\begin{align} \dim (N_{g\circ f})+\dim (R_{g\circ f})&= \dim(N_f)+\dim (R_f)\\ &\leq \dim(N_f)+\dim (V)\\ &=\dim (N_f)+\dim (N_g)+\dim (R_g) .\end{align}$$ Note $R_{g\circ f}\subseteq R_g$. So $\dim (R_{g\circ f})\leq \dim (R_g)$. That is $\dim (R_g)-\dim (R_{g\circ f})\geq 0$. Hence $$\dim (N_{g\circ f})\leq \dim (N_f)+\dim (N_g)+\dim (R_g)-\dim (R_{g\circ f}).$$ **How to reach desired result?**

Comment: I essentially used all three relation, as you suggested in hint 1. Your hint 2 may be is circular, i.e. whatever expression for $\dim (R_f)$, that can be obtained using three relation (of rank nullity theorem). Btw, I am trying to prove $\dim (N_{g\circ f})\leq \dim (N_f)+\dim (N_g)$.

Comment: I have edited the answer, hope this makes things clear.

Comment: OK, but do you agree now with the result $\dim(N_{g\circ f})=\dim(N_f) + \dim(N_g\cap R_f)$ ? That is what OP wanted to show and it can be proven by combining the three equations I've given. Now, $N_g\cap R_f \subset N_g$ and hence $\dim(N_g\cap R_f )\leq \dim(N_g)$ which gives your inequality when combining with OP's equality.

Comment: Ohh…. How did I miss that !?

Answer (score 10):

Here's one possible approach. If a vector is in $\ker f$, then it will certainly be in $\ker(g\circ f)$, but a vector $v$ could also "survive" $f$ (that is $f(v)\neq0$, so $v\notin\ker(f)$), but have $f(v)\in\ker g$ so that still $g(f(v))=0$. The term $\dim(\operatorname{im}(f)\cap\ker g)$ in a sense measures how much this second possibility adds to the dimension of $\ker(g\circ f)$, because in that case $f(v)\in\operatorname{im}(f)\cap\ker g$.

To make the idea precise, one may note that for the purpose of determining $g\circ f$, one may replace $g$ by its restriction to $\operatorname{im}(f)$ (since any vector to which $g$ gets applied in the setting of $g\circ f$ lies in $\operatorname{im}(f)$)
$$
  g\circ f = g|_{\operatorname{im}(f)}\circ f
$$
from which its follows that
$$
  \operatorname{im}(g\circ f) = \operatorname{im}(g|_{\operatorname{im}(f)}).
$$
Now you can apply the rank-nullity theorem successively to $g\circ f$, to $g|_{\operatorname{im}(f)}$, and to $f$ to obtain the required identity of dimensions:
$$\begin{aligned}
  \dim\ker(g\circ f)&=\dim U-\operatorname{rk}(g|_{\operatorname{im}(f)})\\
   &=\dim U-(\dim\operatorname{im}(f)-\dim\ker(g|_{\operatorname{im}(f)}))\\
   &=\dim\ker(f)+\dim(\ker(g)\cap\operatorname{im}(f))
  \end{aligned}
$$

Another approach is to observe that the space $\ker(g)\cap\operatorname{im}(f)$ is precisely the image of $\ker(g\circ f)$ by $f$ (again the observations of the first paragraph apply; you can show both inclusions easily). Then apply the 
rank-nullity theorem to the restriction of $f$ to $\ker(g\circ f)$.

Comment: What if the nullity of f is non-zero, and you compose f with itself. The kernel cannot be of dimension 2 for given a certain number of compositions (and the matrix form of f) you get the zero matrix?

Comment: @AlecTeal: Sorry, I don't understand at allwhat you are saying. Is there a relation with the current question?

Comment: I think so. I have a 4x4 matrix with characteristic poly $(\lambda-1)^4$ I want to find the minimum polynomial, this has all the same roots with the property that $m(A)=0$, I've used a calculator to find $(A-1)^2=0$ (the zero matrix). By this conclusion this means the intersection of the kernel of f and image of f is non-empty (you use f and g, I am composing f with itself, and A is the matrix of f)