# NullSpace of AB if $[A,B]=0$ and $AB\neq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Edited question.

Is it true that for $x\notin\mbox{null}(A)\cup\mbox{null}(B)$, then $ABx\neq0$? Alternately, for what x is it true that $ABx\neq0$?

Thanks!

Comment: It's always true that $\text{null}(B)\subset \text{null}(AB)$; in addition, $\text{null}(AB) = \text{null}(BA)$, hence at least we must take $\mbox{null}(AB)=\mbox{null}(A)\cup\mbox{null}(B)$.

Comment: yep thanks, I edited the question then!

Comment: null stands for kernel?

Comment: @wisefool yes, it does: null=nullspace

Comment: I see the set inclusion property mentioned in the first comment above, but am uncertain how to prove rigorously the equivalence of $\mbox{null}(AB)=\mbox{null}(A)\cup\mbox{null}(B)$?

Comment: [Cross-posted to Math.Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/142705/22840).

Comment: A union of two subspaces is not a subspace unless there is inclusion between the two subspaces (in which case the larger one is also the union). If you mean the sum of the subspaces, please say that.

Answer (score 1):

If $A=B$ are nilpotent but $A^2\neq0$, then you conditions are satisfied but $\ker(A)=\ker(B)\neq\ker(AB)=\ker(A^2)$. So any $x\in\ker(A^2)\setminus\ker(A)$ will show your first guess wrong. Even for commuting $A,B$ there is way to express $\ker(AB)=\ker(BA)$ in terms of other kernels.

Comment: Does $[A,B]=0$ indicate that $A=B$ nilpotent?

Comment: @ChristiaanHattingh: No $[A,B]\equiv AB-BA$ so it means that $A$ and $B$ commute. Nilpotency was not required in the question, nor was $A=B$, but it does provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, referring to the comments, it is not true in general that NS$(AB)=$NS($A)\cup$ NS($B$) (NS referring to null space here). A simple counter example: \begin{equation} A=\begin{bmatrix}2 &1\\2&1\end{bmatrix},\; B=\begin{bmatrix}1 &2\\3&4\end{bmatrix},\;x=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\-2\end{bmatrix}.\end{equation}
You can verify that $x \in$ NS($A$), but $x \notin$ NS($AB$).

Ok - so in terms of a characterization of NS($AB$) in terms of NS($A$) and NS($B$): note that $Bx$ is in the column space (I will indicate this as CS) of $B$. So if

- CS($B)\cap$ NS($A)=\{0\}$ we have NS($AB)=$ NS($B$).
- CS($B)\cap$ NS($A)=$ CS($B$) we have $ABx=0$ for all $x$.

So these are the two extreme cases and there is then a range of cases in-between.

edit: ok, so I first then concluded that maybe (CS($B)\cap$ NS($A)) \cup$ NS($B)=$ NS($AB$), but as pointed out by Marc, this is also wrong since the union of subspaces is not in general a subspace (*basic mistake!*). My answer is based on general $A$ and $B$ and not on commuting matrices. Sorry I misunderstood the question, but hopefully there is at least some contribution in my answer.

Comment: Again the subspace union must certainly be replaced by a sum. But even then it fails; take $A=B$ nilpotent.

Comment: hi marc. are you referring to a direct sum? Yes, it seems it is difficult to express the kernel of $AB$ directly in terms of kernel of $A$, since $A$ "acts" on the product $Bx$ and not directly on $x$. So as pointed out in your answer below any argument based on $x \in ker(A)$ is usually not valid because it might be that $Bx \notin ker(A)$ - I made that same mistake in my attempted conclusion above. So it seems CS$(B) \cap$ NS($A)$ is just an indicator of how large the dimension of $ker(AB)$ will be? do you have any comment on this Marc?

Comment: Just to add that my answer does not assume $A=B$ nilpotent - I am not familiar with the notation $[A,B]=0$, so maybe I missed that...anyway I would appreciate an answer on my comment above in terms of general matrices $A$ and $B$ instead of nilpotent matrices that are equal, just for my own enrichment. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I mean one should write a sum of subspaces $X+Y$ (not necessarily direct) instead of $X\cup Y$ both in the question as in your answer. The point is that $X\cup Y$ is in general not a subspace, in which case it cannot possible be a null space (kernel) of anything, nor a column space (range) for that matter.

Comment: And for the dimensions, yes it does hold that $\dim\ker(AB)=\dim\ker(B)+\dim(\ker(A)\cap\operatorname{Range}(B))$, see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/202710/ .

Comment: Thanks Marc, for both comments...oi, basic mistake...but ok, I'm still just a student...thanks for the input.