# Prove that $ \dim(\ker(g \circ f)) = \dim(\ker(f)) + \dim(\ker(g) \cap \operatorname{im}(f)). $ What is the error in this approach?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f : U \to V$ and $g : V \to W$ be linear transformations on the vector spaces $U$, $V$, and $W$ respectively. Then Prove that :

$$
\dim(\ker(g \circ f)) = \dim(\ker(f)) + \dim(\ker(g) \cap \operatorname{im}(f)).
$$

**Attempt:**  It's clear that $$\ker(g \circ f))= \ker f +\{\operatorname{im} f \cap \ker(g)\}$$

Then
$$\dim \ker(g \circ f))= \dim \big (\ker f +\{\operatorname{im} f \cap \ker(g)\} \big )
\tag{1}
$$

> If $\ker f \bigcap \operatorname{im}f=\emptyset$, then , $(1)$ becomes an external direct product and the dimension adds up. Otherwise, $\dim \ker(g \circ f)) \le \dim \big (\ker f)+\dim \big(\{\operatorname{im} f \cap\ker(g)\} \big )$

Could someone please pin point the error. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Well, $\textrm{ker}f\subseteq U$ and $\textrm{Im}f,$ $\textrm{ker}g\subseteq V$, so the kernel you're writing up isn't well defined.

Comment: I think your approach is fundamentally wrong. Just because the equation holds, this doesn't mean the spaces are the same.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/202710/214353

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing that *is* clear is that $\textrm{ker}(g\circ f)=f^{-1}(\textrm{ker}(g))$.

Now, $f$ induces an isomorphism $\varphi:U/\textrm{ker}f\to \textrm{Im}f,$ and since $\textrm{ker}f\subseteq f^{-1}(\textrm{ker}g),$ we have
\begin{align}
dim(f^{-1}(\textrm{ker}(g))&=dim(f^{-1}(\textrm{ker}(g)\cap \textrm{Im} f))\\
&=dim(\textrm{ker} f)+dim(f^{-1}(\textrm{ker}(g)\cap \textrm{Im} f)/\textrm{ker}f)\\
&= dim(\textrm{ker} f)+dim(\varphi^{-1}(\textrm{ker}(g)\cap \textrm{Im}f))\\
&=dim(\textrm{ker} f)+dim(\textrm{ker}(g)\cap \textrm{Im}f),
\end{align}
since $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.